# Do I copy the Flask folder or install afresh?

Tags: python, virtualenv

It's my first time with Flask. I installed Flask by following this tutorial http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world. However, I want to use another tutorial simultaneously which means i should create a virtual environment in another folder. My question is: Do I have to go through the whole process of installing Flask and its extensions one by one or can I copy the flask folder that was initially created when I was using the previous tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a new virtual environment and `pip install` the required modules again.

Just copying the old virtualenv folder won't work, since virtualenv hardcodes some absolute paths that won't work in the new location.